# Variable went wrong after selecting another worksheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Following is the code on which I have been working on. However, I realized that something went wrong when I select another worksheet from the same workbook.

The variable `ShiftName` seems to change when it goes through the `Sheets("Cash").Select` in the below code.

I believe that the Column for `ShiftName` changed from "B" of worksheet "ShiftRoster" to "C" of "Cash" which caused my output for `ShiftName` to be wrong.

I would like to check if there is any way to solve this?

```
Sub Testing()
    Sheets("Shift Roster").Select

    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find("LEAVE").Activate
    r1 = ActiveCell.Row

    Dim ShiftRowName As Integer
    Dim ShiftColName As String: ShiftColName = "B"
    Dim ShiftColLeave As String: ShiftColLeave = "E"
    Dim ShiftName As String
    Dim ShiftReason As String

    Dim CashRowName As Integer
    Dim CashColName As String: CashColName = "C"
    Dim CashColLeave As String: CashColLeave = "H"
    Dim CashName As String
    Dim CashLeave As String

    ShiftRowName = r1 + 1

    Do While Cells(ShiftRowName, 1) <> ""
        ShiftName = Cells(ShiftRowName, ShiftColName)
        ShiftReason = Cells(ShiftRowName, ShiftColLeave)

        If ShiftName = "" Or IsEmpty(ShiftName) Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            'SOMETHING WENT WRONG FROM HERE ONWARDS
            Sheets("Cash").Select

            Range("C1").Select
            Cells.Find("Name").Activate
            r2 = ActiveCell.Row

            CashRowName = r2 + 1

            Do While Cells(CashRowName, 1) <> ""
                CashName = Cells(CashRowName, CashColName).Value

                If CashName = "" Or IsEmpty(CashName) Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    MsgBox ShiftName
                    End If
                CashRowName = CashRowName + 1
            Loop

            End If
        ShiftRowName = ShiftRowName + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, stop using `Select` and the `*.Active...` properties.  They are inherently unreliable and also slow.

Comment: @RBarryYoung what should I use instead?

Comment: You should use direct ranges and save your object instances in variables with `SET`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qualify your range/cells methods:

instead of

```
ShiftReason = Cells(ShiftRowName, ShiftColLeave)
```

use

```
ShiftReason = Sheets("Shift Roster").Cells(ShiftRowName, ShiftColLeave)
```

so your code knows *exactly* which sheet you're referring to. Without qualifying your ranges it will assume you are referring to the `ActiveSheet` object.